# Fake Intel CPUs?

Tags: cpu

I recently purchased a processor off [eBay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBay) that was labelled as an [Intel Core i5-2520M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i5_microprocessors#.22Sandy_Bridge.22_.2832_nm.29). It came shipped in just a tray, not the original box, but the processor and all its markings look perfectly legitimate.

My system BIOS reports it as a `Genuine Intel(R) CPU 0 @ 2.50GHz` and shows the CPU-ID as `206A5`, which, when I stick it into Google, turns up the Intel Core i7-2720qm instead.

The CPU seems to work fine for the most part and runs Windows 8 64-bit without issues, although it is giving me some trouble with [AMT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Active_Management_Technology), but I'm not sure whether this is a CPU or a motherboard issue.

So, this leaves me with a couple of questions:

- Is it possible to update the microcode of a CPU to pass it off as a different one?
- Is it normal that a genuine CPU gets reported as "CPU 0" in the BIOS rather than its actual ID?
- Could this chip be an engineering sample?
- Is there a software tool that will check whether a processor is genuine?

I ran [CPU-Z](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-Z) and it reports the following:

```
Name           Intel Core i5 2450M (hmmm...)
Code Name      Sandy Bridge
Max TDP        35 W
Package        Socket 988B rPGA
Technology     32 nm
Core Voltage   0.792 V
Specification  Genuine Intel(R) CPU 0 @ 2.5 GHz (ES)
Family         6
Ext. Family    6
Model          A
Ext. Model     2A
Stepping       5
Revision       D0
Instructions   MMX,SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4.1,SSE4.2,EM64T,VT-x,AES,AVX
```

Should it look like this for a 2520M CPU?

Comment: what're you using for the information? On the off chance someone has the same processor, you might be able to check with them. I'm also wondering, since this is a mobile chip, it might be some bios/firmware wierdness with the motherboard. The big difference between a core i7 and a core i5 of the same generation would be the l3 cache, and you can check that - the processor you think you have has 4mb, and the other has 6 I believe

Comment: Mind running cpuz and showing what it reports? http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z/versions-history.html

Comment: hmm http://prd1glbser.cps.intel.com/gserial/home.aspx might be of use, you can use the ULT number to try to work out more details on it.

Comment: @spuder Done... See above

Comment: http://ark.intel.com/products/53452/ intel page on the 2450M

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Unfortunately it didn't come in a box, just the tray...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I guess I mistyped it in Google... This would explain why AMT is not working...

Comment: @MarkusA: You could ULT number on the processor a shot anyway. Chances are this is a OEM chip, but worth a try, nonetheless

Comment: "CPU 0" would be the number of the CPU in the system (i.e. the first CPU enumerated).

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to make illegal clones of an Intel Core i7?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/48738/5830) (@JourneymanGeek pointed it out in a comment to [the accepted answer](http://superuser.com/a/635575/53590) but I think it belongs here).

Comment: Yeah, though in this case cause it mentioned the engineering samples - which @dragonlord had mentioned.

Comment: Just curious: is the capitalization really "INtel(R)" or was that a typo?

Comment: @rbito Sorry, that was a typo, I'll fix it...

Comment: @SimonRichter "CPU 0" actually was not just the CPU number, it truly is the CPU ID given by Intel (see my answer).

Comment: Intel doesn't sell _mobile_ CPUs in retail boxes anyway, only in trays. Only desktop and server CPUs are sold in both boxes and trays.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I didn't know that! I've been trying to avoid tray-only products where possible, but if this is actually a legitimate packaging, I might be able to go for some of the better deals next time! Thanks! (↑)

Comment: Right. If you look up the CPU on [ARK](http://ark.intel.com/) it will tell you which packaging the CPU is (or was) available in. Though either is legitimate; tray packaging is meant for computer manufacturers and system builders who don't need all the extra cardboard or the heatsink/fan, and who often buy in bulk.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: some mobile CPUs are available boxed, but they are rare and expensive. Example: http://www.amazon.com/Intel-Core-i7-4910MQ-Quad-core-Processor/dp/B00K0VA3LA (*Haswell* Socket G3; part number BX80647I74910MQ)

Comment: @DragonLord Yes, that's true. Also seems to be relatively new. Anyway, anyone can look this info up at http://ark.intel.com/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's an engineering sample (emphasis added):

> Specification  Genuine Intel(R) CPU 0 @ 2.5GHz **(ES)**

For more information, see this Intel page: [Information about Intel Engineering/Qualification Sample Processors](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005719/processors.html)

Comment: heh, I missed that, despite explictly mentioning engineering samples in my answer. Its the little things ;p

Comment: Yep, you're correct. It's an engineering sample. After looking again, it even said so on the ebay sales page in the fine print... Thanks for the link, too. Good to know! +1 √ :)

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/48738/is-it-possible-to-make-illegal-clones-of-an-intel-core-i7 entirely relevant. Annoyingly, I was looking at this and didn't make the connection ;p

Comment: good if you want to collect things. They are rarely available. On the other hand not suitable for production. Until everything works, you can use it at home for gaming. :C)

Answer (score 18):

Well, you got shipped a newer processor than what you ordered, with a marginally lower clockspeed and a few features disabled. Unless it was a hell of a deal, you might want to yell at the ebay vendor.

To sum up all the things in the comments and a few extra details - various levels of fake processors exist [from repacked engineering sample chips](http://www.techarp.com/showarticle.aspx?artno=527&pgno=2), to the lovely, and [utterly non functional core i7 920 newegg accidentally shipped a few years ago](http://www.geek.com/chips/hands-on-unboxing-the-fake-intel-core-i7-920-1363005/). You'd notice these are repacked chips, or complete bricks, rather than cunningly modified, or homebrewed processors.

[image]

[image]

In this case though, you got a newer [core i5 2450](http://ark.intel.com/products/53452/) rather than an older, slightly faster [2520](http://ark.intel.com/products/52229/) which has a few additional features. While some intel processors can be softmodded to unlock [additional cache and features](http://www.bit-tech.net/news/hardware/2010/09/20/intel-release-upgrade-cards/1), I couldn't find any reference to radical softmodding. While you didn't get what you paid for, the chip you have is probably as it was designed and manufactured by intel. I'd suggest taking a closer look at those chip markings - since they would confirm it. It would be possible, and a little crafty to swap those heatshields, but its unlikely since its too much work.

The [product identification utility](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/processors/toolspiu) by intel might be of interest here as well

Comment: Unfortunately it was exactly those features (Vt-d and vPro) that I was trying to get... It's for a server build...

Comment: with a mobile processor?

Comment: Just needs to run an encrypted RAID... this way it's easy on the power consumption and since it supports vPro, Vt-d and AES-NI, it has all the hardware features and acceleration I need... :)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek for anyone looking these days, some others you see occasionally now are BGA CPUs fitted with sockets, and sometimes a Chinese x86 CPU rebranded as an Intel (and I'm sure AMD) CPU.

Answer (score 7):

As noted by *DragonLord*, the CPU I purchased on ebay is an [Engineering Sample](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/CS-030747.htm).

I have meanwhile received a replacement processor that is actually a genuine Core Intel i5-2520M.

Here are the differences:

1. This one, the system BIOS identifies correctly as an

   ```
   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz
   ```

   with CPU-ID `206A7`.

   So, the `CPU 0` part of `Genuine Intel(R) CPU 0` was actually **NOT** an indication that this is the first CPU in the system (as suspected in some answers/comments here), but really part of the CPU-ID given by Intel for this particular (and maybe all) Engineering Sample CPU.
2. CPU-Z now reports (differences marked):

   ```
   -> Name           Intel Core i5 2520M
      Code Name      Sandy Bridge
      Max TDP        35W
      Package        Socket 988B rPGA
      Technology     32nm
      Core Voltage   0.752V
   -> Specification  Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2520M CPU @ 2.5GHz
      Family         6
      Ext. Family    6
      Model          A
      Ext. Model     2A
   -> Stepping       7
   -> Revision       D2
      Instructions   MMX,SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4.1,SSE4.2,EM64T,VT-x,AES,AVX
   ```

   (I didn't mark the Core Voltage as different since it keeps fluctuating a bit anyways)
3. What do you know? AMT now works perfectly!

I will leave *DragonLord's* answer as the accepted one, since he figured out correctly what was going on.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a knock-off x86 compliant CPU isn't the same as a fake memory card. Worst case someone tried to pass off an older model but Intel changes the socket design every couple generations. Not to mention these CPUs also contain a GPU.

- Yes it's possible to update the microcode - Intel offers paid upgrades for some of their CPUs.
- *CPU 0* simply refers to "the first CPU" if you have a multi-CPU or multi-core system.
- Doubtful it's a sample.
- Run a benchmark and compare the output with online results for that CPU model
- Intel AMT requires a compliant BIOS

Comment: Interestingly his processor claims to be a *newer* model of a *later* generation than what he bought, tho both are cross compatible. This is just plain wierd. He bought a SB core i5, and his system thinks its a IB core i7

Comment: That's true, it should be a CPUID 0206A7h

Comment: @justbrowsing *CPU 0* does actually NOT mean "first CPU" (see my answer) and it was a sample after all. But the rest of your answer is useful. Thanks.

Comment: My answer was written **BEFORE** the output from `CPU-Z` was posted. In certain CPU stat utilities (mostly Linux-based) CPU 0 refers to either the first CPU or first core. See `/proc/cpuinfo` for example.